# Not able to view the Graphical Layout of XML files

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem when running a program using fragments for Android with Eclipse ADT Plugin.

When I try to view the graphical layout of the layout xml files, it shows 
"The project target (Android 4.0.3) was not properly loaded."

can anybody please help me with the isssue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is your 4.0.3 SDK installed?

Comment: Have you tried to restart eclipse? And clean and rebuild the project?

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility is permissions.

If you installed the SDK to your "Program Files" folder you might need to run Eclipse as an administrator so you can have write access to the SDK directory.  (Or you could move the SDK).

Comment: this question has been viewed over 1000 times and i am the first upvote for you? ha weird, considering your answer worked for me. thanks @barak

Answer (score 0):

Here are some assumption:

- Make sure the "SDK Location" in Windows->Preferences->Android is set up correctly.
- In the "Android SDK Manager": Check whether you have Android SDK 4.0.3 installed.

If it won't work try to change the Project Build Target:

Open "Properties" of your project. (Alt+Enter while project in Package Explorer is selected.) Navigate to "Android" and select another Android SDK.

However you should check whether you need to use 4.0.3.

While coding you should try to choose a build target as small as possible to prevent yourself from using methods and classes which aren't supported. However it is recommended to choose the newest for compiling since there might be some optimizations of older methods in newer SDK versions.
You can use fragments for pre honeycomb with the support package which is located in your Android SDK folder: /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar

Comment: Thanks, It helped. Some updates where available in the SDK Manager.

Comment: @AkhilaNair you really should accept an answer if it worked for you.